# Android subprojects with Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm working on migrating by Gradle build files to the Kotlin DSL and I encounter an issue.

On my parent `build.gradle`, I have the following piece of code

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${Version.kotlin}"
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

subprojects {
  afterEvaluate { project ->

    if (project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application') ?:
      project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.library')) {

      android {
        compileSdkVersion = Android.SDK_COMPILE
        defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion Android.SDK_MIN
          targetSdkVersion Android.SDK_TARGET
          versionCode = Android.VERSION_CODE
          versionName = Android.VERSION_NAME
        }
        ...
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

This allows me to configure in only one place all the modules that are android applications or libraries.

However this doesn't seem to work when I migrated to kotlin:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath(Dependency.androidGradle)
    classpath(Dependency.kotlinGradle)
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
  }
}

subprojects {
  afterEvaluate {

    if (project.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.application") != null || 
        project.plugins.findPlugin("com.android.library") != null) {

      android { <<<<------------ Unresolved reference: android
        compileSdkVersion(Android.SDK_COMPILE)
        defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion(Android.SDK_MIN)
          targetSdkVersion(Android.SDK_TARGET)
          versionCode = Android.VERSION_CODE
          versionName = Android.VERSION_NAME
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The error is `Unresolved reference: android` and it looks like the `android{}` block is not recognized by the script compiler.

My theory is that the `if` checking for the subproject type is not enough, and I might have to cast or get a reference to some object in which I can call the `android{}` block, but honestly I do not know enough.

Any clues?

Comment: Why are you wrapping it all in an `afterEvaluate` block? Except you are fiddling with compile tasks or what not, you dont need the `afterEvaluate` block. Just use `project.plugins.withId("<plugin-id>") { ... }`

Comment: Do you find solution how to access "android" inside subprojects block gradle kotlin-dsl?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gradle Kotlin DSL determines the dependencies for *each script* from the gradle classpath plus the applied plugins. That's why its recommended to use the `plugins { ... }` block in the Kotlin DSL.

You need to add the android and kotlin plugins to your root without applying it.

```
plugins {
  id("<android-plugin>") version "<plugin-version>" apply false
  id("<kotlin-plugin>") version "<plugin-version>" apply false
}
```

Unfortunately, that will still not generate the static accessors for the root build script but it will give you access to the plugin classes within the script and you can reference them like:

```
subprojects {

  // BasePlugin is the common superclass of the AppPlugin and LibraryPlugin which are the plugin classes that "com.android.application" and "com.android.library" apply
  plugins.withType<BasePlugin> {

    // BaseExtension is the common superclass of the AppExtension and LibraryExtension which are the extension classes registered by the two plugins to the name "android"
    configure<BaseExtension> {

      // This block is typed correctly
      defaultConfig {
        // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It all makes sense, will give it a try soon!

Comment: This was a hard one, but finally got it working. For the second code part, I had to use `plugins.withType(BasePlugin::class.java)` instead of `plugins.withType(BasePlugin)`

Comment: do u have any sample code to apply this? i'm trying to move module build.gradle.kts to root build.gradle.kts using subprojects

Comment: @AlexBurdusel plugins.withType<BasePlugin>

Comment: In my case I had to change *BasePlugin* for *AndroidBasePlugin*. All of the rest remains the same